# Synchronise changes in profile information across SO sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, profile-sync

When I change my profile information in one of the SO sites (Stackoverflow), the changes don't seem to be reflected across all the sister sites. Shouldn't that be the case?

Edit: Just to clarify, I'm talking about the "About Me" section and the other profile information, and not badges, reputation (obviously) etc.

Comment: yep this is planned for accounts tab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can now copy profiles via the buttons labelled "copy from {site}" on the accounts tab of the user page.

For "blind" souls like KronoS here's where it's at:

[image]

Then you'll get this:

[image]

Comment: this has moved to the edit page on your account

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps there should be a core section of the bio that's shared and then a section that's unique for each site.

At the moment all mine are the same, but that's down to laziness on my part.

Comment: That would definitely be a bit strange, but it is an interesting compromise.

Comment: I was thinking that you might want to stress your language skills on SO, your admin skills on SF and your general willing to help nature on SU.

Comment: The more I think about that, the more I like it.

Answer (score 2):

I could see this as a potential desire (especially if you went through the steps to associate your OpenID across all accounts for the 100 rep bonus).

One thing that I would like to add is that if this ever happened, it should be an option because I know that I personally like to include different information on my different profiles (such as my faux badges).

Answer (score 0):

Came here to post this myself, after making a minor (yet essential - employment status) update and having to copy/paste to serverfault and meta.

If (when?) this is done, it definitely has to be an optional thing. An [answer to another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sync-meta-user-accounts-daily-with-other-family-sites/229#229) sums up this need nicely.

I think it would probably be adequate to have a "propagate changes to:" list at the bottom. You make one edit intended to be seen on all sites, then you can go back and tweak it if necessary.

This might not be the easiest approach to take, but since some people will maintain some differences in all profiles, perhaps a diff/merge option should be made available for this.