# User details not maintained in a common place

Tags: discussion, user-interface, profile-page, user-accounts

Why are user details not maintained in a common place across sites? If I need to change something (not that there are many things a user can change), I will have to change it in all three (or four or many more, in the near future) places, rather than just one.

Comment: did you post this as Community Wiki? 'cause somehow both your question and my answer are CW without any indication in the revision history.

Comment: Yes, it was posted as CW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jeff, in [this similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2714/synchronise-changes-in-profile-information-across-so-sites), the feature is coming up.

Comment: Yes. Checked the Copy Profile buttons in the accounts section of the profile. Cool :)

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of [account association](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites), I believe [syncing of data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sync-meta-user-accounts-daily-with-other-family-sites) between the user profiles of the sites is right around the corner. However, some people will want to maintain different data on different sites (this will become more prominent as the number of sites grows), so I hope that this will be an opt-in feature.

Comment: Yes, I checked the links. Some don't want consistent profiles :)

Answer (score 0):

I for one would probably have a very different profile on superuser, and I should *probably* update my profile for SF; simply, the geek-details on my SO account aren't really appropriate if I am asking about getting the CD drive working on ubuntu (or whatever).

Comment: Ok ... I see ... you got a point there.

Comment: cd drive...you mean the cup holder?